# Suction cup with a 1/4" TS cable?

Tags: identification, components

I found this weird component at a resale store. I feel like it is some sort of pick up, but I'm not sure. Lots of things could have a quarter inch TS cable coming out of it and there are no markings on it whatsoever (save for a small "26" on the suction cup section, which I feel like is just for the suction cup).

The weird thing is that the swivel bracket uses a hardened bolt.

I feel like this thing isn't meant to bear any seriously high loads or anything.

What do you think it could be?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You haven't shown the front of the device.  That bolt looks like a stainless steel to me.

Comment: Is it a microphone?

Comment: The two dashes marked on the bolt head indicate stainless steel.

Answer (score 7):

Stainless steel hardware suggests a marine application of some sort.

My guess: An ultrasonic transducer meant to be stuck to the side of a boat, just under the waterline with the flat side facing down. The plug would go to a portable sonar ("fish finder") of some sort.

Comment: so it could be a sonar transducer?

Comment: Yes, a fish finder.  https://www.westmarine.com/buy/garmin--suction-cup-transducer-adapter--4336707

Comment: Camille Goudeseune: Opening that link may result in *"Page Blocked. We have detected that you are visiting us from a country with Global Data Protection restrictions (GDPR). Due to requirements placed upon West Marine as a result of Global Data Protection Regulation, we are not permitting internet traffic to our website from certain countries in order to avoid any violations. No tracking or performance measurement cookies were served with this page."*. Time to use a VPN connection...

Comment: Unfortunately, VPN (NordVPN) messes (makes inoperable) with both IRC (freenode, [sigrok](https://sigrok.org/)) and FTP to my web hotel...